# Should I ground the metal box for 14-50 outlet?

Tags: electrical

I just finished installing a 14-50 outlet in my garage. I haven't hooked it up to the breaker box yet. I used 6/3 nm-b cable with ground. I made the wire and ground connections to the outlet but I didn't connect the ground wire to the metal box and now I get the feeling that's wrong. Is it? I didn't see a screw on the metal box to clue me in. Should I connect the ground to the metal box?

Here is a picture of the outlet and links to what's behind the plate.

Thanks

Metal box: https://www.homedepot.com/p/RACO-4-in-Raised-Ground-Welded-Square-Electrical-Box-8232/100578083

Metal box cover: https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-Square-Box-Cover-for-30-or-50-Amp-Receptacle-Case-of-10-RS13-10R/202597322

Wall plate: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Legrand-Pass-Seymour-2-Gang-1-Power-Outlet-Wall-Plate-Stainless-Steel-SL703CC12/202313808?keyword=785007180268&semanticToken=20030000+++%3E++++st%3A%7B785007180268%7D%3Ast++cn%3A%7B0%3A0%7D++cn%3A%7B0%3A0%7D++785007180268+%7Bproductkey%7D+qu%3A%7B785007180268%7D

Cable clamp: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-8-in-Non-Metallic-NM-Twin-Screw-Cable-Clamp-Connectors-5-Pack-20511/100133208?keyword=051411205119&semanticToken=20030000+++%3E++++st%3A%7B051411205119%7D%3Ast++cn%3A%7B0%3A0%7D++cn%3A%7B0%3A0%7D++51411205119+%7Bproductkey%7D+qu%3A%7B51411205119%7D

[image: outlet]

Comment: It would complete the description if you would provide a picture of the breaker for this installed in your panel.

Comment: That looks like the cheaper version 14-50 outlet from home depot rather than the much more expensive Hubbell industrial grade 14-50.  Are you using it to charge an EV car?  Have you had issues with it overheating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You want one of these

[image: lay in lug]

### attached with one of these

[image: topaz ground screw]

### right here

[image: raco box]

Then you can lay the bare ground in the lay in lug, no wire nut in the box, no pigtail ... at least IMO that's the easiest way to ground this.

The green screw is typically used for grounding but you can really use any 10-32 machine screw.

Be sure to choose a lay-in lug that accepts #6 wire.

Comment: Yeah, an Ilsco GBL-4 or equivalent would be about ideal for this application

Comment: Can you tell me if a metal box is required for a 14-50 outlet or is a plastic box ok?

Comment: @MilkyTech: This is a 4 year old question. You should post a new question.